# Not able to install rstanarm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: r, installation, ubuntu-18.04, stan, rstanarm

I'm not able to install `rstanarm` on `R 3.5.3` running on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. I used the following commands:

```
install.packages("rstanarm")
```

and

```
devtools::install_github("stan-dev/rstanarm", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

and both throws the following error:

```
Execution halted
Makevars:17: recipe for target 'stan_files/lm.cc' failed
make: *** [stan_files/lm.cc] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rstanarm’
```

**sessionInfo**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] usethis_1.5.0  devtools_2.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        ps_1.3.0          prettyunits_1.0.2 rprojroot_1.3-2  
 [5] digest_0.6.18     crayon_1.3.4      withr_2.1.2       assertthat_0.2.1 
 [9] R6_2.4.0          backports_1.1.3   magrittr_1.5      rlang_0.3.4      
[13] cli_1.1.0         curl_3.3          fs_1.2.7          remotes_2.0.2    
[17] testthat_2.0.1    callr_3.2.0       desc_1.2.0        tools_3.5.3      
[21] glue_1.3.1        pkgload_1.0.2     compiler_3.5.3    processx_3.3.0   
[25] pkgbuild_1.0.3    sessioninfo_1.1.1 tcltk_3.5.3       memoise_1.1.0    
>
```

Comment: Do you have everything from https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Linux#c-toolchain-configuration ?

Comment: Since you are using a newer Ubuntu, it's unlikely, but worth checking g++ version.

Comment: Thanks @BenGoodrich for your comment. I've already attempted all this but still it is not working. Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: What is shown **before** the words `Execution halted`?

Comment: @duckmayr:  `"/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript" -e "source(file.path('..', 'tools', 'make_cc.R')); make_cc(commandArgs(TRUE))" stan_files/lm.stan
Error: (converted from warning) S3 methods 'print.stanfit', 'as.array.stanfit', 'as.matrix.stanfit', 'as.data.frame.stanfit', 'is.array.stanfit', 'dim.stanfit', 'dimnames.stanfit', 'names.stanfit', 'names<-.stanfit', 'pairs.stanfit', 'loo.stanfit' were declared in NAMESPACE but not found`

Comment: @MYaseen208 Have you tried (from the terminal) `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install r-cran-rstan`?

Comment: @duckmayr: Yes, I've alread tried `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install r-cran-rstan` which throws the error: ` E: Unable to locate package r-cran-rstan`. Any thoughts

Comment: @MYaseen208 Sorry, I forgot to add that you need to add the PPAs first: `sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"` and `sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u"`

Comment: @duckmayr: I also added the PPAs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191779/discussion-between-duckmayr-and-myaseen208).

Comment: do you have a `.RProfile` file either in you home directory or in `R` directory , if you do ,then please can you share the content of it here or add it to your question ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04 + R 3.5.3, you can install `rstanarm` via the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"
sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-cran-rstanarm
```

Some background info on why you may have had trouble previously:

The RStan installation guide for Ubuntu is out of date for those using R 3.5.x.

[Ben Goodrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762912/ben-goodrich) linked in the comments to the RStan GitHub [Guide to Installing RStan on Linux](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Linux#installing-from-the-repository). There they advise the following for Ubuntu:

```
# Add marutter's c2d4u repository, (and rrutter for CRAN builds too)
sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"
sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rstan
```

However, for newer versions of R, you need to instead do the following

```
# Add marutter's c2d4u repository, (and rrutter for CRAN builds too)
sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"
sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rstan
```

This should install RStan for you just fine on Ubuntu 18.04 + R 3.5.3.

Comment: Got installed. However, `library(rstanarm)` throws  the following `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstanarm’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘rstanarm.so’ not found`. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Does running `find . -name 00LOCK-rstan*` from the terminal (from your home directory) return anything?

Comment: Did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

First time when this error occured and assuming that you have a `.RProfile` in your `R` root directory you will most likely find a line where it says : `setwd("~/R")` ,go ahead and comment this line and restart `R` and get a new session , then run again : `install.packages("rstanarm")` you should be able to install `rstanarm` successfully ,  don't forget to uncomment `setwd("~/R")` after the installation , the reason of the this error to occur  is that rstanarm  install script assumes that the working directory is the root of the package directory which not the case when you call `setwd()` in .Rprofile 
if you want to give this a try .. please remove the `rstanarm` that you installed using PPA