# how to install rstan in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, rstan

I'm trying to instal the rstan in Ubuntu 18.04. I started with

```
 apt-get install r-cran-rstan
```

and it showed dependence on the packages : r-cran-ggplot2 , r-cran-pkgbuild and r-cran-v8.
Then while trying to install all of them, another dependence on r-api-3.5, which I tried to install with

```
  apt-get install r-api-3.5
```

Then I saw the following message :

> The r-api-3.5 package is a virtual package provided by:    r-base-core
> 3.6.3-1bionic [Not a candidate version]
>
> E: The 'r-api-3.5' package has no candidate for installation

I read some tutorials like this one: [Not able to install rstanarm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611697/not-able-to-install-rstanarm-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts) saying I should add the ppa by doing :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter"
sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-cran-rstanarm
```

and I did. But it's still not working. My R version is the latest one. I didn't find documentation about r-api-3.5 in Ubuntu. If anyone knows how to solve it, please tell me.

Comment: While questions asking how to install *programming tools* are on-topic, I think it's better to ask on Ubuntu question sites.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue and my colleague as well.
We just jumped directly to the install and it worked fine.
In short:

```
remove.packages("rstan")
if (file.exists(".RData"))
file.remove(".RData")
install.packages("rstan", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies = TRUE)
library(rstan)
example(stan_model,run.dontrun = TRUE)
```

Source and more detailed explanation: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started#installation-of-rstan

Comment: Thank you Lours! I was only able to solve this problem after installing the version 3.5 of R. Now it works.